# Increase speed/efficiency of code by avoiding apply() function

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop, apply

I have the following dataframe:

```
Model <- c("HS5", "HS5", "HS5","HS4")
Length <- c(6, 6, 6, 6)
Code <- c("030299", "010121","030448","030324")

df <- data.frame(Model,Length,Code)


Model   Length   Code
HS5       6     030299
HS5       6     010121
HS5       6     030448
HS4       6     030324
```

I want to apply the following code to each row and generate the outcome as a new column

```
library(concordance)

concord(sourcevar = (each row of 'Code' column), origin = as.character(character in 'Model' column) , destination = "HS4", dest.digit = as.numeric(number in 'Length' column), all = F))
```

By using the code below, we apply ['concordance'](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/concordance/concordance.pdf) (Page 6) function to every row and generate an outcome, however, `apply(`) function works too slow on big data, my question is, if it's possible to somehow increase the speed of this code, even by changing `apply()` function

```
df$New <- df$Code
df[df$Model != "HS4", ]$New <- apply(df[df$Model != "HS4", ], 1, \(x) concord(sourcevar = x[colnames(df) == "Code"], 
                                               origin = x[colnames(df) == "Model"], destination = "HS4", 
                                               dest.digit = x[colnames(df) == "Length"], all = F))
```

[The previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71870478/how-to-apply-function-to-each-row-of-dataframe-in-r/71870645?noredirect=1#comment127004430_71870645)

Answer (score 1):

You can likely speed it up by taking advantage of how `concord` accepts a vector input of the `sourcevar` argument.  The challenge is that the other arguments don't accept vector inputs.  Therefore, you might try a strategy to perform a vectorized operation on `sourcevar` for each unique combination of the other arguments (origin, dest.digit, destination).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(concordance)

# create data sample
Model <- c("HS5", "HS5", "HS5", "HS4")[1:3]
Length <- c(6)
Code <- c("030299", "010121","030448","030324")
df <- expand_grid(Model, Length, Code) %>%
  expand_grid(id = 1:5) 
print(df)
#> # A tibble: 60 x 4
#>    Model Length Code      id
#>    <chr>  <dbl> <chr>  <int>
#>  1 HS5        6 030299     1
#>  2 HS5        6 030299     2
#>  3 HS5        6 030299     3
#>  4 HS5        6 030299     4
#>  5 HS5        6 030299     5
#>  6 HS5        6 010121     1
#>  7 HS5        6 010121     2
#>  8 HS5        6 010121     3
#>  9 HS5        6 010121     4
#> 10 HS5        6 010121     5
#> # ... with 50 more rows

# call concord vectorized over sourevar
tic <- Sys.time()
df %>% 
  group_by(Model, Length) %>%
  mutate(
    value = concord(Code, origin = unique(Model), dest.digit = unique(Length), destination = "HS4", all = FALSE)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 60 x 5
#>    Model Length Code      id value 
#>    <chr>  <dbl> <chr>  <int> <chr> 
#>  1 HS5        6 030299     1 030289
#>  2 HS5        6 030299     2 030289
#>  3 HS5        6 030299     3 030289
#>  4 HS5        6 030299     4 030289
#>  5 HS5        6 030299     5 030289
#>  6 HS5        6 010121     1 010121
#>  7 HS5        6 010121     2 010121
#>  8 HS5        6 010121     3 010121
#>  9 HS5        6 010121     4 010121
#> 10 HS5        6 010121     5 010121
#> # ... with 50 more rows
print(Sys.time() - tic)
#> Time difference of 0.1580009 secs

# not vectorized
tic <- Sys.time()
df %>% 
  mutate(
    value = lst(sourcevar = Code, origin = Model, dest.digit = Length) %>% 
           pmap_chr(concord, destination = "HS4", all = FALSE)
  )
#> # A tibble: 60 x 5
#>    Model Length Code      id value 
#>    <chr>  <dbl> <chr>  <int> <chr> 
#>  1 HS5        6 030299     1 030289
#>  2 HS5        6 030299     2 030289
#>  3 HS5        6 030299     3 030289
#>  4 HS5        6 030299     4 030289
#>  5 HS5        6 030299     5 030289
#>  6 HS5        6 010121     1 010121
#>  7 HS5        6 010121     2 010121
#>  8 HS5        6 010121     3 010121
#>  9 HS5        6 010121     4 010121
#> 10 HS5        6 010121     5 010121
#> # ... with 50 more rows
print(Sys.time() - tic)
#> Time difference of 4.267002 secs
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: number of bracket are incorrect

Comment: Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `value = concord(...)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: Model = "HS3", Length = "6".
Caused by error in `concord_hs()`:
! Conversion dictionary not available.
Backtrace:
  1. ... %>% ungroup()
  8. concordance::concord(...)
  9. concordance::concord_hs(...)
 10. base::stop("Conversion dictionary not available.")
 Error in mutate(., value = concord(Code, origin = unique(Model), dest.digit = unique(Length), : 
i The error occurred in group 1: Model = "HS3", Length = "6".
Caused by error in `concord_hs()`:
! Convers dictionary not avai.

Comment: I added a closed parens, which should fix one issue.  Is your Length stored as character?  I ask just based on your error message; I see quotes around the 6.

Comment: Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `value = concord(...)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: Model = "HS4", Length = 6.
Caused by error in `concord_hs()`:
! Conversion dictionary not available.
Backtrace:
  1. ... %>% ungroup()
  8. concordance::concord(...)
  9. concordance::concord_hs(...)
 10. base::stop("Conversion dictionary not available.")
 Error in mutate(., value = concord(Code, origin = unique(Model), dest.digit = unique(Length), : 

i The error occurred in group 1: Model = "HS4", Length = 6.
Caused by error in `concord_hs()`:
! Conversion dictionary not av

Comment: still the same problem. can you run this code on the df given above?

Comment: @Josh it seemed to complain trying to convert HS4 to HS4.  I updated with a simple benchmark demonstrating the speed-up with vectorized function call.

Comment: but my dataframe is different, there is not only HS5. As you see above there is HS4 too. So it isn't is possible to include it too?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71941494/increase-speed-efficiency-of-code-by-changing-apply-function

Comment: I used only HS5 because those where the only valid code transactions from your question.  If you can provide some other valid combinations of sourcevar + origin, I can update my solution.